# Whenever I type or paste text with the phrase "B_ne = B_e – B_i – B_il" in it into Office, it changes my system language to Russian

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language

I am running Windows 10. I have Russian and Ukrainian languages installed. I'm trying to type the phrase "B_ne = B_e – B_i – B_il". Whenever I type or paste this phrase into an outlook email or word document, it translates the phrase into Russian and changes my system language. It also doesn't let me undo this change.

I thought initially it was just the "B_il", but that is not enough. I've tried working back and forth through the phrase and the only thing that seems to trigger it is the entire phrase, not one part.

What gives? And how do I stop it?

I tried removing Russian and Ukrainian from my language bar, but that hasn't worked. Also I'd ideally like to keep them installed while being able to type mathematical equations into Outlook without it trying to convert everything to Cyrillic text.

Comment: Does the phrase have any meaning in either of the languages?

Comment: 1. Are you using any macros? Try disabling all macros and test. 2. Also, try another version of Office... BTW, LibreOffice *Writer* does not behave this way. 3. Be sure the characters you're pasting are not Cyrillic: compare pasted text in a hex editor.

Comment: Please check whether this article is helpful, "[Keyboard Changes to Unwanted Foreign Language](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008715_Keyboard_Changes_to_Unwanted_Foreign_Language)".

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No, it's a mathematical equation.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No macros. I don't have any other version of Office, and this is the one that my company provides me and I have to use. I am definitely not pasting Cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the option to "detect language automatically."

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Outlook? Or a shared configuration in one of the other office applications?

Comment: You can certainly do it in Word. Reviewing > Language > Proofing Language > Uncheck the box. This is a system setting for Word. I do not know how it does anything to other Office programs.

Comment: I did it in Word and it looks like it fixed it for Outlook as well. Not sure if there's a way to do it directly in outlook though.

Comment: Word and Outlook are the two programs in Office most connected.